# Can someone explain to me the rule in JavaScript that applies here?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I was playing around with JavaScript, and I ran into a problem. I was trying to make two buttons change the written text above them, with the change being different depending on what was already written. There were only 4 potential options. So what I thought was to just use an if and else ifs to make it work. But it didn’t work. Then over the next couple of hours I went over it again and again and couldn’t make it work. Finally I came up with an idea that made it work but I don’t know why.

**The above is very long so you if you’d rather skip it, just read this:**
*Why does **a)** work and not **b)**?*

**First my HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets.css">
        <script rel="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="boopFunction()">
    
        <h1 id="boop"></h1>
    
        <button onclick="ggFunction()">Leave
        </button>

        <button onclick="eeFunction()">Enter</button>



    </body>
</html>
```

**Then what worked, a):**

```
var Boop = document.getElementById("boop");



/* onload welcome */
function boopFunction() {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[4];
    Boop = Poob[4];
}
    
    
    
    

/* leave button */
function ggFunction() {

    if (Boop == Poob[0]) {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[1];
    Boop = Poob[1];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[2]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[1];
        Boop = Poob[1];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[1]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[3];
        Boop = Poob[3];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[4]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[1];
        Boop = Poob[1];
    }
}



                                            
/* enter button */
function eeFunction() {

    if (Boop == Poob[1]) {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[0];
    Boop = Poob[0];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[3]) {
        
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[0];
    Boop = Poob[0];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[0]) {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[2];
    Boop = Poob[2];
    }
        else if (Boop == Poob[4]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[0];
        Boop = Poob[0];
    }
}
```

**Lastly what did not work, b):**

```
var Poob = ["Welcome!", "Goodbye!", "You're still here?", "You're still outside!", "Hello there!"];


var Boop = document.getElementById("boop");



/* onload welcome */
function boopFunction() {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[4];
}
    
    
    
    

/* leave button */
function ggFunction() {

    if (Boop == Poob[0]) {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[1];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[2]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[1];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[1]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[3];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[4]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[1];
    }
}



                                            
/* enter button */
function eeFunction() {

    if (Boop == Poob[1]) {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[0];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[3]) {
        
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[0];
    }
    else if (Boop == Poob[0]) {
    document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[2];
    }
        else if (Boop == Poob[4]) {
        
        document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML = Poob[0];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP! This makes a lot more sense! Here is the code *(though it’s really just for fun which is why it’s random)* that I changed it to with the information you all gave me!**

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets.css">
        <script rel="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="olFunction()">
    
        <h1 id="banner"></h1>
    
        <button onclick="leaveFunction()">Leave
        </button>

        <button onclick="enterFunction()">Enter</button>



    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var Poof = ["Welcome!", "Goodbye!", "You're still here?", "You're still outside!", "Hello there!"];


var Crash = Poof[4];



/* onload */
function olFunction() {
    document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML = Crash;
}
    
    
    
    

/* leave button */
function leaveFunction() {

    if (Crash == Poof[0]) {
    
        Crash = Poof[1];
    }
    
    else if (Crash == Poof[2]) {
        
        Crash = Poof[1];
    }
    
    else if (Crash == Poof[1]) {
        
        Crash = Poof[3];
    }
    
    else if (Crash == Poof[4]) {
        
        Crash = Poof[1];
    }
    document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML = Crash;
}



                                            
/* enter button */
function enterFunction() {

    if (Crash == Poof[1]) {

        Crash = Poof[0];
    }
    
    else if (Crash == Poof[3]) {
        
        Crash = Poof[0];
    }
    
    else if (Crash == Poof[0]) {

        Crash = Poof[2];
    }
        else if (Crash == Poof[4]) {
        
        Crash = Poof[0];
    }
    
document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML = Crash;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend replacing these variable names to be less similar (`foo` and `bar` are widely used placeholders) -- Can you also point to where you believe the issue is in the code? The code takes longer to find differences in than reading the intro paragraph.

Comment: You're comparing `Boop` to strings in `Poob`, but in the case b) `Boop` is an `Element`, not a string. In case a) you're reassigning `Boop` to be a string so it works. You don't need `var Boop = document.getElementById("boop");`, because it's never used as an `Element`.

Comment: Thank you tromgy that makes sense. And Slbox, In the working one, I added all the Boop = Poob[].

Answer (score 0):

Reason is easy. Because you have two function and each your function  doesn't include else condition. For initialize your data is html element

```
document.getElementById("boop");
```

so u don't enter any of condition so nothing working. Here you should use

`document.getElementById("boop").innerHTML;`

As solution you will give initialize value like your working example or add else statement and inside it give expected value

Comment: Thank you I’ll check it out as soon as I can to see what you’re talking about haha